# TinyMCE - Image Tools Plugin - Converting to blob

Tags: image, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4 + [Image Tools](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/imagetools/) Plugin.

When I use the cropping/rotation or any other image edit option, **the resulting image is saved as a blob.**

When I view the HTML source code, all the images are saved as blob.

I want to get it as a **base64** image.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those blob images will be sent to the server as Base64 images.  If you configure TinyMCE to process these images as documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

...when the data arrives at the server they will be Base64 images.  The browser shows blob URLs to avoid showing you a very long Base64 binary string.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Let me test it and post the results.